# Parallel IO & Append

Tags: fortran, fortran90

When I run my small-scale parallel codes, I typically output N files (N being number of processors) in the form `fileout.dat.xxx` where `xxx` is the processor number (using `I3.3`) and then just `cat` them into a single `fileout.dat` file after the code is finished.

My question is can I use `ACCESS='append'` or `POSITION='append'` in the `OPEN` statement and have all processors write to the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, no. POSITION='append' merely says that the file pointer will be at the end of file after the open statement is executed. It is, however, possible to change the file position, e.g. with the BACKSPACE, REWIND or such statements. Thus, Fortran POSITION='append' does not correspond to the POSIX O_APPEND, and hence a POSIX OS cannot ensure that all writes only append to the file and do not overwrite older data.

Furhtermore, in case you run your code on a cluster, be aware that O_APPEND does not work on many networked file systems such as NFS.

In order to do parallel I/O with several processes/threads writing to a single file, use ACCESS='direct' or ACCESS='stream' and have the processes agree on which records/byte ranges to write to.